# RegEx Pattern to Match Only Certain Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a newbie to RegEx, and this particular issue is flummoxing me. This is for use with a JavaScript function.

I need to validate an input so that it matches only these criteria:

- Letters A-Z (upper and lowercase)
- Numbers 0-9
- The following additional characters: space, period (.), comma (,), plus (+), and dash (-)

I can write a pattern easily enough for the first two criteria, but the third one is more difficult. This is the last pattern I managed, but it doesn't seem to work with the test string `Farh%%$$+++,`

Here's the pattern I'm trying

```
[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789\\+\\.\\,\\s]*$
```

It's failing in that it's letting characters other than those specified in the text field when submitting the form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I just tested this out, and it seems to work at least from my first round testing.

```
^[a-zA-Z 0-9\.\,\+\-]*$
```

Comment: except that it matches an empty string (and tab charatecter) and you don't need to escape any of those characters

Comment: @SlientGhost Good point on the empty string, but technically anything that allows a space, and using a single character class will allow all spaces.  As for the escaping, I was just being careful, I was running this through a .NET RegEx tester and seeing funny results.

Comment: I think this might do it. Had to add 0-9 to make it match numbers.

Comment: you see, it's not just tabs, in Javascript `\s` matches spaces, tabs, line breaks plus *any* Unicode whitespace characters, which, it seems to me, is slightly more than what OP wanted.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot the 0-9, and removed the \s

Comment: One question, why is it '\' needed?

Answer (score 17):

The dash needs to be first in order not to be interpreted as a range separator. Also, make sure you anchor your regex with a ^ and $ at the beginning and end respectively so that your entire test string gets swallowed by your regex.

```
/^[-+., A-Za-z0-9]+$/
```

Comment: The dash can also appear at the end or between character ranges in order not to be interpreted as a range separator: `[a-z0-9-]` and `[a-z-0-9]` are valid expressions too.

Answer (score 4):

```
/^[a-z0-9 .,+-]+$/i
```

Answer (score 2):

For validate selector as ID only (according to allowed characters https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

```
var isValidIdSelector = function (str) {
    var regex = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_\-\:\.]*$/gm);
    return regex.test(str);
};
```

Answer (score -4):

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9/&quot&quot\\\]\[:;|=,+*?<>]+$/"
```

allows: alphanumeric + " / \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? <>