# Excel VBA RegEx expressions not always working correctly

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I used the feedback from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555810/regex-pattern-to-match-only-certain-characters) post to construct the following regex expression in Excel VBA:

```
     With myRegEx
     'allow numbers, alphabetic characters, ".,?&?|"
      .Pattern = "[^\x30-\x39\x61-\x7A\\x2E\x21\x26]+"
        'from Space to to Tilde in the assci tablet
        .Pattern = "[^\x20-\x7E]+"
        'match all cases not first occurances
        '.Global = True
    End With
```

take the value from the cell, everything which is not between hex32 and hex 7E is removed.

`wsData.Range("A1") = myRegEx.Replace(wsData.Range("A1").Value, " ")`

of course I iterate through my collection but for the sake of the example I removed the rest of the code.

The code as such works fine  it will remove all non printable ASCII characters **BUT** if you have a large string in a cell, let's say 1500 characters, the algorithm will not remove it. It will also not throw an error. So it just does not do anything and you are not aware of it. I have no idea how to force the RegEx on the entire cell contents and what the maximum number of characters is which the RegEx supports?

I know it is a bit odd of a question but I would like to find out how I can force the regex to do a check on the entire cell contents.

many thanks in advance

Comment: Try with `.Global = True` and `.MultiLine = True`

Comment: Damn! such a simple thing! I finally ran the complete data check (500000+ data cells) and now it works! many thanks for the suggestion. I did not know that it was that simple! It works now as I expect it to be working. kind regards,